# Dimensions of container in inspect element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When we inspect element in web page.It shows dimensions of container as 216.34x34.56 (this is dummy dimension for illustrations).I wanted to know what is the unit of this dimension?

Comment: I'm sure the units are in css pixels.

Comment: I bleieve what the browser inspect facility is showing you is the offsetWidth/Height of the element and as @cherryguy says those are in CSS px units.

Comment: Yeah got it thanks!!